# What did Stephen R. Donaldson mean by "there is hope in contradiction"?

Tags: paradox, thomas-covenant

One of the many recurring sayings in [*The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant) is said in full by one of the characters (a magic lord named Mhoram) as:

> When you have come to the crux, and have no other recourse, remember the paradox of white gold. **There is hope in contradiction.** [emphasis added]

I've never fully understood what this was supposed to mean. I've thought of the following three interpretations, but I'm not sure which one fits how the storyline actually worked out:

1. A literal, overly formal interpretation: in mainstream human logic, contradictions imply anything you wish them to, so Covenant can appeal to the paradox to grant his wish for victory in the end, as long as he gets to the heart of the paradox first. This explanation seems contrived, not in the spirit of Donaldson's *leitmotifs*, and wouldn't really account for why the enemy fails (i.e. why wouldn't the enemy have "gotten there first"?).
2. If your premises are genuinely inconsistent, you can expect that only one of them will prove true in the end. But then what ground would Covenant have for thinking that the "right" horn of the dilemma would end up as reality?
3. If your premises *seem* inconsistent, but both seem true as well, you can expect that if you find a meaningful way to *reformulate* them, they'll turn out actually jointly true. This is the interpretation that rings most true, to me, but did Donaldson ever really confirm that this is how the saying is to be taken?

Comment: I recall something from one of the books of the Second Chronicles of Covenant in which an evil magician wanted to use the white gold ring to make a specific kind of magic, saying something to the effect that the impure metal (pure gold alloyed with nickel and zinc) would create pure magic. Perhaps this is the contradiction referred to: purity created from impurity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you looking specifically for what Donaldson has said about it, or are you willing to consider answers from other sources (and which)?  Are you looking for in-universe answers only?

Comment: @DavidW mostly if SRD said anything about it, I used to follow his General Interview and Kevin's Watch but left those behind some time ago. He's a very logical author, so I can dimly imagine him thinking something along the lines of explanation #1, but I don't think any of his characters besides Linden Avery would've been of a mind to say such things, and anyway I don't think the saying was often, if ever, directed at her.

Comment: @StanleyWebb I forgot about that. I wonder if SRD was using "contradiction" in an indirect or irregular sense, then? I think the wizard said something about "the very paradox of which the Earth was made" in that connection.

Comment: I did not read Donaldson's point about paradox in terms of formal logic.